# What returning when coding a REST API that finds no value?

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm wondering about what should REST Api returns when we use Spring Data in order to find an object by Id for example ?

I saw that a lot of people would return 404 Not found and other 204 No content .

but imagine that a client has always to catch the exception or check if returned object is not null .

I think it is better to return always a no Null object even empty so we could respect The null object design pattern.
I want your advices guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST doesn't care very much; if the resource has a current representation, then you send that representation and annotate it as such in the response headers.  If it doesn't have a current representation, then you send a representation of an error, with appropriate annotations in the headers.

But REST doesn't offer any guidance as to which/when resources should have current representations.

If there is a default representation for the resource, then yes, it is reasonable to use it even though there is not matching data in your database/document store/file system/....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preference you can return 404 or 204 or if you want to send any custom message you can do that too. but overall I think it's better to send 404. it's easy for the API consumer to get the error code and show necessary message.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a response code `200` with a body indicating the details.

As, The endpoint exists, the request made was totally valid and could be processed, but there was no match.

If request to the endpoint was not valid, you would look at the other 4xx errors.

But, It also depends on consumer implementation also.

Comment: As a consumer , what is the DTO reponse that  I have to put as a return of the endpoint? Can the dto be always not null even data not found ? such as returned object dto like : returnedobject =[]